# Applying same filter to multiple layers (not Photoshop)

Tags: layers, photo-editing, filter

Applying same filter to multiple layers is possible in Photoshop but for us non-Photoshop users, is there any other option available ?
Gimp has a GAP plugin, but Gimp doesn't work on my Windows10-64bit machine.

If there are any other alternatives to achieve this operation?

Answer (score 0):

Affinity Photo allows you to select several layers at the same time and apply the same filtering to all selected layers

[image]

In Krita you can define filtering with Krita's own filters to happen as "filtering mask" which is effectively like Photoshop's  layer style except it works with different set of filterings. To apply the same filtering to another layer you must Ctrl+Drag the filtering mask on the wanted layer in layers panel.

Add-on filters, I mean G'MIC collection, do not know filtering masks, but you can apply last G'MIC filter to another layer simply changing the active layer and clicking Filter > Re-Apply last G'MIC Filter.

Finally there's some on-line image editors. At least Photopea allows one to select several raster layers and filter them all with one command.

Comment: thanks for the answer,yeah Gmic contains a great variety of usable filters but their is no way to automate it in Krita .But in Krita there is an option to create a  shortcut to  apply the "last used" Gmic filter.But still this is a manual process.Gmic does have a command line interface tool ,it could be a better option for automating this process.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it in GIMP without any scripts, or GAP.  It's a little more manual but only requires two keyboard shortcuts, so it's pretty fast.  A script could even probably be written to automate it, but I have no idea how to do that.  Anyway, here's the keyboard shortuct method:

1. Choose the top layer, and apply any filter
2. Press <kbd>↓</kbd> (the down arrow key) to select the next layer down
3. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> applies the last filter used
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until finished.

Obviously, this may be a little tedious if you have hundreds of layers.